# Dynamically create class properties for google datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to get a similar result to:

```
class MyClass(db.Model):
    field=db.IntegerProperty()
```

i.e., the object of this class should have `field` on a list of its properties:

```
o=MyClass()
o.properties()
```

However, these fields should be created dynamically based on the definition of their names and types, as in the example below:

```
class MyClass(db.Model):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        defs={'field':'d','otherfield':'s'} #'d' for integer, 's' for string
        for key in defs:
            typeof=defs[key]
            val=db.StringProperty() if typeof=='s' else db.IntegerProperty()
            #tried these lines below... but properties() are still empty :|
            setattr(self, key, val)
            setattr(self.__class__, key, val)
            setattr(self.__class__, key, property(lambda self: self.__dict__[key]))
            self.__dict__.update({key:val})
        db.Model.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

None of the `setattr` lines worked (they create fields but not properties); the list of properties in the object remains empty, therefore it seems that I cannot use such objects in `db.GqlQuery()`. I don't want to use the "Expando" model, because in my case the list of fields and their types is known and it is constant. Using `eval` would probably do the job but would be ugly.

I believe the two simple lines that start my post can be achieved dynamically in a simple way... I must be missing some obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do something like this.  There's a few problems here, `db.WhateverProperty()` are designed to be on the *class*, not on an instance.  Just like regular properties, they don't have a lot of meaning when they're attached to an instance instead of the class.  I think that your best bet is to use `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` on the `StringProperty` contents and handle the errors as strings.

Alternatively, you could have 2 properties/atributes on your model and then you can write access methods which delegate to the proper method based on type.

If you're not opposed to using the `ndb.Model`, you might be able to get away with `ndb.JsonProperty` -- but I'm not sure how that gets indexed for use in queries.